# Caught exception while handling client http traffic for one node (4 node cluster) ElasticSearch

Tags: java, apache, elasticsearch, netty, logstash

```
[2015-01-14 04:14:41,855][WARN ][shield.transport.netty   ]org.elasticsearch.common.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:923)
at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.callDecode(FrameDecoder.java:425)
at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.messageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:303)
at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70)
at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791)
at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.handler.ipfilter.IpFilteringHandlerImpl.handleUpstream(IpFilteringHandlerImpl.java:154)
at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:559)
at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:268)
at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:255)
at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:88)
at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.process(AbstractNioWorker.java:108)
at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:318)
at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:89)
at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:178)
at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I am getting this exception in the logs of one my nodes(10.168.226.129).
ClusterHealth is green in clusterhealth API.
Cluster Topology:
4 nodes cluster,ElasticSearch 1.4.0,serverJre1.8.25, shields for authentication and encryption.

Can you please point me what is broken?

Comment: If you are using shield, you must have a support contract -- why not ask support for help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the exception it looks like the remote peer is plain text connection and no tls/ssl.

Comment: yes that was it,indexer was hitting cluster with http not https,,,,thanks